# How to get all contents of oracle meta data? with respect to Time_stamp

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

How to get all content of oracle meta data?

I want to access the meta data of oracle. I want to get the time_stamp for every event generated by any user like `(select, update, insert, delete)`. How to get this information from the meta data of the oracle database?

For example. If User-A comes and insert some record into the oracle database. Then that Time of insertion is stored in the meta data. How to access that time?

Answer (score 0):

### per-command timestamp

If you want per-command timestamp, that is, if you want to get the timestamp of some precise command like `INSERT INTO this VALUES(that_and_that)` then:

```
AUDIT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON user.the_table ...

SELECT * FROM dba_audit_trail ;
```

### per-row timestamp

If you want per-row timestamp, that is, if you want to check each row of a table and see when each row have been last UPDATEd, then you need your own customized solution with `CREATE TRIGGER  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger separately for each table . There is no out-of-box solution for this in Oracle.